# c++ weird error message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Someone has reported a bug in my program, which brings up the following error message:
[image]

The error occours in a C++ DLL of the program, which was compiled by VS2008. I can reproduce the error, but am not able to find out what´s the problem. I´ve already done a bunch of tests   for memory leaks or wrong alloctions, but with no success.

Now the weird thing: when I add a main function to the code, compile it as an EXE and then run the exactly same thing, all is ok. The error occours only as a DLL.
The next strange thing is, that when I press "Ignore", the program continues and does its job as expected.

So, I´m looking for 2 types of answers:
- Answers that help me find the bug
- Answers that help me to "auto-ignore" or hide this errormessage, so that it does not occour. That would be ok, since there is no difference in the result.

I´m thankful for any help or advise.

Thanks!

**Update**

Like Joachim Pileborg said, I´ve created a simple test c++ project, that calls my DLL, and it works perfectly! The program that normally calls the DLL is written in DELPHI, so I think it could be a bug of DELPHI... Weird: The call of the DLL works for 99.9999..%, but in one specific case, there occours an error IN the Dll. It´s not the call that fails... Really, really strange story :S

Comment: Have you tried making a minimal executable that loads the DLL, instead of making an executable out of the actual DLL? Do you get the same problem then? Also, since you obviously have the source to the DLL, why not build it in debug-mode, and press "Retry" do debug it?

Comment: Do you have the source code for the offending line?

Comment: Have you tried clicking "Retry" to debug the application?  That should show you what function call is throwing the error. (Off topic... worst button choice ever)

Comment: If you are okay with just _hiding_ the error message, I think in the release mode it won't show. But you ought to find the actual error: the message is a sign of a grave mistake, and the fact that if it works for now doesn't mean it won't crash at client's machine.

Comment: "auto-ignoring" such an error is not a good idea.

Comment: Also to add, the hex representation of that number is 0xFFFFFFFC which may or may not help you track down the problem

Comment: Gonna state the obvious here... just debug it?

Comment: .@Joachim Pileborg Like you said, I´ve created a simple test c++ project, that calls my DLL, and it works perfectly! The program that normally calls the DLL is written in DELPHI, so I think it could be a bug of DELPHI... Weird: The call of the DLL works for 99.9999..%, but in one specific case, there occours an error IN the Dll. It´s not the call that fails... Really, really strange story :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the debugger, I was able to see the call stack, and what function in the code displayed the error. After searching for this routine, I could find out how to disable displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok... that is a negative number. The simpler thing... perhaps your code is doing a malloc with an invalid\negative size?

The strange thing is that that number in binary is 11111111111111111111111111111100, probably your size calculation is wrong. It can be however a more complicated error, for example due a buffer overflow.

You should not ignore this error at all, can be a symptom of a more complicated and dangerous error.
Try to debug your allocation, try to get exactly the piece of code that is doing this invalid allocation.

You can overload the new operator or redefine the malloc replacing them your debug functions where you can check the passed arguments (size).

Comment: Are you sure you've got the binary transcription right? It doesn't seem to me.

Comment: the number in binary is actually `11111111111111111111111111111100`

Answer (score 1):

4294967292 - that is `(unsigned)-4`. You are either doing some computation of the size to be allocated wrong, some integer has overflown or somesuch.

I'd try to put a breakpoint on `malloc` (or whatever allocation function that is) and check where does the bad value come from.